# How does r clear all global environment quickly

Tags: r

Is there a function or command in `R` which could clear all the `global environment`, just like `clear` in `Matlab`.
I only know the function `rm` that needs me to put every variable name in it if I want to remove it. That's really not convenient.

Thanks

Comment: `rm(list=ls())` .

Comment: Do you use RStudio? If so you can click the broom icon in the "Environment" tab. There are R commands to achieve the same thing but given this is something this is generally done manually I think using the GUI is OK.

Comment: rm(list = ls())?

Comment: Yeah, really a good answer. Thanks.

Comment: This question and its answer (in the comment above) is much clearer and to the point that the question of which this one has been marked as a duplicate. I've voted to reopen this question. If anything the dup should go the other way.